# Automated Mailing System with Python

Tags: python, cron, task, mailing

I’m not a very experienced programmer. Trying to learn python by myself. I want to create a python file that will run every morning. And when this program runs, it will check all the employees first hired date to the company and if it’s the anniversary, it will automatically send an e-mail to that employee saying “thank you etc...” using an html template. And also it will send the same e-mail to that employee’s manager.

So my idea is to create a dictionary containing the employees and also add a field to indicate their manager.

Every morning the code will compare each employees hiring date with that current comparing date and when it finds out it’s the anniversary for that employee it will send this celebration e-mail to him/her and to his/her manager.

I’m planning to write the code first with python. After I finish the code, I’ll try to move it to django. (I haven’t learnt django yet so I can’t do it now)

I’m also not very good at using classes. So I’m planning to do this by creating functions.

Do you have any suggestion for me? Is there any point I should be paying attention? Or is there any method you would suggest me to use?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: An idea: set up a script that runs a query using SQLite and use smtplib to send email, create a cron job for that script.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of question is too broad for this site. You have to split the full job in elemental tasks: 1/ read the employee list with their manager and first hire date. 2/ build an HTML message from an employee name 3/ send the message to the employee and his/her manager 4/ make a python script that combines everything and 5/ launch the script from cron. First do some research on each task and feel free to ask more specific questions here if you need help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to create the database with sqlite3 and I can read from the database. Now I need to somehow make a calculation buy I don’t know how to do it. I add the employement dates to the db as DATE format and as ‘YYYY-MM-DD’. The type of this entry is a sqlite class I guess. How can I make a comparison between today’s date with datetime.date and employement date? I need to trigger the mailing function when it is the anniversary date. For example if the employement date is 2016-04-22 then the code should work every year on 22th of Apr. But not all the years are 365 days.